# Lower bound on the probability that a string has a fixed substring

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, bit-strings

Let us suppose we have a fixed bit string *P* of length $n$. We have to prove that there is a constant $k>0$, such that for any $n$, if we uniformly randomly generate a bit string $Q$ of length $k\cdot2^n$, the probability that $Q$ contains $P$ as a continuous substring is greater than 0.5, where the probability of getting a 0 is 0.5 (1 as well consequently).

My first intuition was defining a random variable $X$ as the number of occurrences of $P$ in $Q$ and using that $E[X]=(k\cdot 2^n-n+1)/2^n<k$. Then, we can represent our goal probability as $P[X\geq 1]$. However, using Markov inequality and its reverse results in either an upper bound or a lower bound too loose.

In order to use Chebyshev's bounds, we would have to calculate the variance, which seems impossible to me as it depends on $P$. (Unless one can work with bounds of variance?)

Other things I have tried are:

- Dividing the positions where the substring could start into independent cases, defining binomial variables, and trying to bring them back together.
  -> The bound seemed to be too loose.
- Using Chernoff's bounds on the aforementioned binomial variables.

Another way one could prove the statement would be to show that there are $> 2^{k\cdot 2^n-1}$ bit strings of length $k\cdot 2^n$. Tried using the Inclusion-exclusion principle, but couldn't get anywhere.

I'm trying to find a solution that does not use Markov's chain for example, as we just have to show a lower bound instead of giving the exact probability.

Comment: The probability will be lowest when $P$ has the pattern $111\ldots111$ and highest when $P$ has the pattern $111\ldots110$  (other patterns also hit these extremes)

Comment: Rereading this makes me wonder about $k$, since for given $n$ clearly some $k$ are too small (e.g. $k=1$) and others more than enough (e.g. $k=2^n$).  Are you asking for $k$ as a function of $n$, or a $k$ that works for all $n$?

Comment: $k$ has to be a positive constant that works for all values of $n$.

Comment: Empirical investigation seems to suggest that $k=2$ ought to work, perhaps as low as $k= \frac{89}{64}=1.390625$

Comment: DId you just bruteforce it? or was there a formula that nicely sums it up? I tried to find a lower bound with Inclusion exclusion formula, did up to the second term and was still smaller than 1/2 :<

Comment: I "brute-forced" it for the pattern $111\ldots111$ up to $n=20$.  Not checked.  If $P_n(x)$ is the probability that the substring first appears when the string is of length $x$ then it seems that $P_n(x)=0$ when $n\le n-1$, $P_n(n)=2^{-n}$, $P_n(n+1)=2^{-n-1}$ and $P_n(x)=P_n(x-1)-P_n(x-n-1)2^{-n-1}$ when $x \ge n+2$